# Is there an environment variable in Docker Hub Automated Builds that tells you the location of the repo root?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build, auto-build

Let's say my repo is called `X`.
I have these files

- `X/worker/Dockerfile`
- `X/worker/hooks/build`

Inside `Dockerfile`, I have this command `COPY worker/requirements.txt ./requirements.txt`

Inside `build` file, I have this command `docker build -f $DOCKERFILE_PATH -t $IMAGE_NAME .`

I use Docker Hub Automated Builds feature to build the image based on the `build` file I have. I set Dockerfile location to `worker/Dockerfile` and build context to `/`.

There is an error saying that `worker` directory is not found when building. I guessed that it's because the current directory on the cloud machine is not set to `X`. So I tried to put `pwd` into `build` file to see the current directory.
The result is `/src/bq2wmtsfppaqsxh3krqkqay/worker`. So my guess is right. It seems that docker rename my repo to a random string and `cd` into `worker` directory when building the image.

There are 2 potential solutions:

1. I want it to not `cd` into `worker` directory because I set build context to `.` in the build command which I want it to refer to `X` not `X/worker`. How can I achieve that?
2. Instead of setting build context to `.`, maybe there is a special environment variable that will tell me where `X` locates. In this case I want a string variable that stores `/src/bq2wmtsfppaqsxh3krqkqay`, is there such a variable that I can use as build context in the build command?

Also is there an example of the exact build command used by docker to do Automated Builds? If I can see the exact build command they use, maybe I'll be able to modify it to suit my needs. I expect it to follow this format: `docker build ...`

Comment: Still not knowing the answer. but the current workaround I use is to put `cd ..` above the `docker build` command.